# Unknown coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

Does anybody know what coordinate system this could be?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Impossible to say. Its corners are pretty much (0,0) and (4000,-2827), and I bet if the image is 4000 pixels by 2827 pixels then its not got any coordinate system attached to it at all.

If you know *where its meant to be on the earth* then you could use something like the "projfinder" website to figure this out. But I'm guessing its not got a reference system and its just indexing pixels from the top left.